# Get user data in marker info window android google maps from firebase database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers, geofire

By using Geofire and Firebase i have implemented the feature to get the user who is nearby,but right now it only shows the marker for the nearby user and i also want the user info to be shown by using the info window.So what to do to make the info window fetch the JSON data from firebase database.By Experimenting with info window i got the results but it only showed me my own info and that was from the client not the database.Here is the code

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (mMap != null){
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            One one;
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_infowindow,null);

                TextView nameInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.usernameinfowindow);
                TextView fromInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filltextfrominfowindow);
                TextView toInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filltexttoinfowindow);
                CircleImageView profileInfo = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.infowindowprofilepic);

                nameInfo.setText(user_name.getText());
                fromInfo.setText(eetsource.getText());
                toInfo.setText(eetdestination.getText());
                return view;
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my database [firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p96Tr.png)
& This is my info window layout

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/infowindowprofilepic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        app:border_color="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/infowindowprofilepic"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infowindowprofilepic"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/infowindowprofilepic">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernameinfowindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:text="@string/user_name_corider"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textfrominfowindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp_padding"
            android:text="@string/from_corider"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filltextfrominfowindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/your_starting_point"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttoinfowindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/to_corider"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filltexttoinfowindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/your_destination"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The pojo class which helped me when fetching details from database in recycler view

```
public class One extends LocationData {

public String name;
public String from;
public String to;
public String when;
public CircleImageView picture;

public One(){
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(One.class)

}

public One(String name, String from, String to, String when, CircleImageView picture) {
    this.name = name;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.when = when;
    this.picture = picture;

}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name", name);
    result.put("from", from);
    result.put("to", to);
    result.put("when", when);
    result.put("picture", picture);
    return result;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

@Override
public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

@Override
public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

@Override
public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

@Override
public void setWhen(String when) {
    this.when = when;
}

@Override
public String getWhen() {
    return when;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have getInfoWindow set to return "null". It's not getting a view to display. You need to add

View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_infowindow,null);

Into get infowindow and set return to view.

return view;

Regards,
-cd